# Redux modifying the a state value without being asked to?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

i'm using redux to manage my state , my initial state in the reducer contains to arrays !
the first one(`games`) is the one that i want to modify , the second one (`InitialGames`) is Initial one that i don't want it to be modified !

the problem is i only make changes on the first array ! but when i console my state after the logic ! i see that both arrays got changed ??? which is confusing !

The case that i'm going into is `PLAYER_DEAD`

**My Reducer**

```
import { ADD_GAME, PLAYER_DEAD, PUT_INFOS, RESET_GAME } from "./actions";

const initialState = {
 games: [],
 InitialGames: [],
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
 switch (action.type) {
   case RESET_GAME:
     state.games[action.payload.gameIndex] =
       state.InitialGames[action.payload.gameIndex];
     console.log(state);
     return state;
   case ADD_GAME:
     return {
       games: [...state.games, action.payload.game],
       InitialGames: [...state.games, action.payload.game],
     };
   case PUT_INFOS:
     return {
       gameInfos: action.gameInfos,
     };
   case PLAYER_DEAD:
    
     let newGames = state.games;
     let newInitialGames = state.InitialGames;

     console.log("Before Changings", newGames, newInitialGames);

     let newTeam = newGames[action.payload.indexGame].teams[
       action.payload.index
     ].players.splice(0, 1);


     console.log(
       "After changings",
       newGames,
       newInitialGames
     );
     return {games:newGames,InitialGames:newInitialGames};
 }
 return state;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be occurring because you're passing the same `action.payload.game` object to both of your arrays here:

```js
return {
  games: [...state.games, action.payload.game],
  //               same objects ---------^------v
  InitialGames: [...state.games, action.payload.game],
}
```

When you access the `.teams` array in your `PLAYER_DEAD` case, you're accessing the same array in memory shared by both `games` and `InitialGames`, the same goes for anything within that array, including the `.players` array within your `.teams` array's objects. Because you're updating your array in place in a non-immutable way by using `.splice()`, you end up modifying your state directly and thus modifying the same `.players` array referenced by both `games` and `InitialGames`.

You need to ensure that you don't modify your state in place by using methods like `.splice()`. For your particular case, you would do something like so:

```js
const newGames = state.games.map((game, i) => i === action.payload.indexGame
  ? game.teams.map((team, j) => j === action.payload.index
    ? {...team, players: team.players.slice(1)} // note slice, not splice
    : team
  )
  : game
);
```

Above, we map your arrays, updating the items when the inndx matches the item to update. When updating the `players` array, we use `.slice()` to remove the first item from the array.

Writing immutable code isn't always easy, that's why redux toolkit has built-in support for immer when you use an API such as [`createSlice()` API](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice) that will allow you to write code like you've been doing the mutates your state. See [here](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers#redux-toolkit-and-immer) for more info.

Comment: Or better, `createSlice` instead of `createReducer` :)

Comment: @markerikson Thanks Mark, agreed `createSlice()` is better (updated my answer to link to that instead)